# Java-like lastIndexOf in c++

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lastindexof

I performed some research on boost and c++ but could not locate anything relevant to my question.  Is there an boost library or STL function that implements  [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has the member function [`rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) which searches from the end and returns the index if found or `std::string::npos` if not. From the linked reference page:

> Finds the last substring equal to the given character sequence.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you might want [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of).

> Finds the last character equal to one of characters in the given character sequence. Returns the position of the found character or npos if no such character is found.

Edit:

Also see hmjd's answer. There are differences between `find_last_of` and `rfind` depending on whether you are searching for a single character, one of many possible characters, or a substring.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use `std::find` with `reverse_iterator`s. For example, you have a vector of ints and you want to find the last 5 in it. You do

```
auto it = std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 5);
```

If you want the index per se, then you can get that from the iterator

```
int index = std::distance(v.begin(), (it+1).base());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both std::string::rfind and std::string::find_last_of are incomplete answers. They works only in the case of one symbol is seaching.

The true lastIndexOf is boost::algorithm::find_last. find_last allows search the whole substring instead of one symbol.