# boost::algorithm::string::finder.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, lastindexof

[Already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557700/java-like-lastindexof-in-c) and received answers about c++ STL but what about boost?

This is a question about boost Finders.  If you have a link to describable boost library implementations I would appreciate it to make hunting the boost library for practical applications easier.

My question is which boost finder most applies to [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))?

Comment: Can you explain your use-case. Why do you need a finder instance instead of using standard (or boost) explicit function to find the last index of a character or pattern? If you just want a function that works for finding the last index of a pattern, use the solution @sftrabbit posted.

Comment: @ViteFalcon Yes, I am looking for a function in boost that finds last index of a pattern and opted to use solution posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off, the simplest option if you're going to search for the last occurrence of a substring is to use `std::string::rfind`:

```
std::string str = "Hello, World!";
int index = str.rfind("o");
```

If you need to use Boost because you want it to work on generic ranges, use `boost::algorithm::find_last`. It takes two ranges. The second range is searched for in the first range.

```
std::string str = "Hello, World!";
iterator_range<std::string::iterator> it = find_last(str, "o");
int index = std::distance(str.begin(), it.begin());
```

If you really want to user a finder, it seems like you're looking for `boost::algorithm::last_finder`. The finders return a function object that takes two iterators as its arguments. The function returns an `iterator_range` You can use it like so:

```
auto finder = last_finder("o");

std::string str = "Hello, World!";
iterator_range<std::string::iterator> it = finder(str.begin(), str.end());
int index = std::distance(str.begin(), it.begin());
```

Comment: Perhaps the easiest thing to do is best for now.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Mushy Just to be clear, you are aware that `std::string` has an `rfind` member function, right? If you're just searching in strings, use that. Use the `boost` algorithms if you need to work on generic containers.

Comment: Yes I know of rfind determined in a link to my original question.  Are you suggesting that the boost library is best or perhaps should only be used on generic containers?  I have a large program employing both generic and non.

Comment: @Mushy It is best to use `rfind` if all you need to do is search for the last occurrence of a substring in a `std::string`. But if you need to search through any type of container, maybe a `std::vector` or `std::set`, you'll want to use the boost algorithms.

Comment: Ahhh ok then and thank you for the clarifications.  I will switch the code to rfind since I am searching a std::string.  But isn't a std::string a container too containing characters and offering some of the standard container operations?

Comment: @Mushy Strictly speaking, `std::string` doesn't meet all of the requirements of a container. It's very nearly a container though. Anyway, the point is, being generic sometimes comes at a price. If you *know* you're using a `std::string`, then there's no point being generic about it.